# Connect Wall - Chromium Minutes Dartboard Days

Tags: knowledge, connect-wall

Here's a connect-wall puzzle inspired by
[An Only Connect Wall](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38928/an-only-connect-wall/40059#40059)
by JonathanAllan.

It's my first of this kind so I've made it relatively easy (I think).  Once you get one correctly, the others should be easy enough, even if you have to google some of the trivia.

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CHROMIUM | GOLD | HOURS | NEUTRAL |
| MINUTES | DWARVES | DEATH | SECONDS |
| DARTBOARD | MOLYBDENUM | BLACKBIRDS | DIAMOND |
| DAYS | CALCIUM | BOND | THE ANSWER |

Find the 4 correct groups and declare yourself this puzzle's connect-wall-smarty-pants-super-expert

Comment: Neautral != neutral?

Comment: @Mithrandir ...yes :|

Comment: I've referenced this CW in the tag info FYI

Comment: ...and yet I missed it's existence until now :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe all the groups are based on

> numbers.

So, we have

> 7: days (/week) dwarves (Snow White, or Tolkien's rings) bond (James) neutral (pH)

and probably also:

> 24: chromium (atomic number) hours (/day) blackbirds (baked in a pie) gold (carats)

I thought briefly that I had the other two groups nailed, but I now think that was probably wrong. I think it's probably

> 42: the-answer (Douglas Adams) molybdenum (at.no.) death (Japanese) calcium (atomic mass of one isotope)

and

> 60: minutes (/hour) seconds (/minute) diamond (anniversary) dartboard (highest-scoring single region)

but am not entirely convinced by the last item in each.

Comment: Gareth, you sly spoil-sport.  You pretty much have it +1

Comment: I've only got one actual group of four so far, though...

Comment: Only one complete and yet 3 categories are correctly named :)

Comment: Two complete now, I suspect.

Comment: (but now being buttonholed by a colleague who annoyingly wants to talk about actual work, so further progress may be delayed :-).)

Comment: OK, I think I've basically got it but am having a blind spot on one of the items.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan: Impressive! Do you mind adding some explanation? I think that 24 for gold has something to do with 24 carats being pure gold and that 7 for neutral is linked via the pH value, but it's not very obvious. How does 42 relate to dartboards and death, for example?

Comment: Yeah, got it now (before seeing BH's last comment, as it happens). I will add some more explanations per M Oehm's request, but note that dartboard=42 was just a mistake and that one actually goes in a different group.

Comment: OK, how does it look now?

Comment: Marking correct.  I guess Calcium is a bit of a vague connection - sorry about that.  I got about 50% of these connections straight from Wikipedia to be honest :)  Well done.

Answer (score 1):

First group:

> Time measure: Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds

Second group:

> Elements: Calcium, Molybdenum, Gold, Chromium

Third group:

> Words starting with D: Dwarves, Dardboard, Death, Diamond

Fourth group ? :

> ??? : Neutral, Blackbirds, Bond, The Answer

Comment: Seems that days would overlap your 3rd group.

Comment: @RobStone: The groups in Only Connect walls aren't exclusive. In the TV show they often make groups that could have five or more items and you have to find the odd one out that can logically go into other groups. (I didn't know that when I tried to solve my first one here on SE and it threw me off track, too)