# An Unfortunate Conundrum Involving Extremes

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, story

> The tide recedes as I sit in the fenced garden on my roof. A jagged rock lies ready to wreck the mariner who errs. A seabird screeches somewhere to my rear. Longing, I look at the world beyond the rail. The earth is green. It is the middle of the day and I am listening to Abba. A beat of wings and the bird comes in sight - nature and I are in sync. He who renounces nature, wherever he may roam, goes nowhere.

What is my number?

**Hint 1**

> Throw up your hands in surrender: this is one of the harder ones.

Comment: I don't know your number, but I am super relaxed now.

Comment: Who are you? If you are another Seabird, you are number 2 :p

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your number is:

> **Thirteen**.

Why?

> The last word in each sentence can be transformed with [Rot13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) to give another English word. That word is described at the beginning of the sentence:
>
> The **tide recedes** as I sit in the fenced garden on my *roof* — **ebbs**.
> A **jagged rock** lies ready to wreck the mariner who *errs* — **reef**.
> A **seabird** screeches somewhere to my *rear* — **erne**.
> **Longing**, I look at the world beyond the *rail* — **envy**.
> **The earth** is *green* — **terra**.
> It is the **middle of the day** and I am listening to *Abba* — **Noon**.
> A **beat of wings** and the bird comes in sight - nature and I are in *sync* — **flap**.
> **He who renounces nature**, wherever he may roam, goes *nowhere* — **abjurer**.
>
> **Throw up** your hands in surrender: this is one of the harder *ones* — **barf**.

Unfortunalely, I haven't got any good explanation for the title.

Comment: There is a superstition regarding the number you discovered. The title also hints at the important parts of each sentence are those furthest from the middle. :-)

Comment: Not my best title, I admit. I also failed to find a way to work in clerk/Pyrex, onyx/balk and fur/she. Congratulations on finding the solution!

Comment: Ah, I see! There's also vex/irk. Green and sync reminded me faintly of [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38928/an-only-connect-wall). So in my case, 13 seems to have brought me luck.