# Deep in the forest... I see something:

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, rebus, steganography

I was walking in the forest and I saw something that caught my eye, since I don't want to tell anybody unworthy of knowing, I made a clue:

`34faP`

If you can solve this, then you may know.

### What did I see?

Hint #1:

> The 51 is irrelevant.

Hint #2:

> **Chr/Edg/Fir** [image]

Comment: Rot13: Gur frpbaq uvag ybbxf yvxr vagrearg oebjfref gb zr. Tbbtyr Puebzr, Zvpebfbsg Rqtr, Zbmvyyn Sversbk. Gur ebgngvbaf ner 'erserfu ohggbaf' va gurfr oebjfref.

Comment: @PL457: rot13(Abj vs lbh pbhyq znxr na rssvat svir-yrggre-pbqr sebz gung bofreingvba ...`:>`) (See my last comment on NL's answer.)

Comment: I like the subtle hint you dropped. And the comment you mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you walked in the forest, you saw ...

> ... **green bark**.

The first step is ...

> ... to treat the clue in the question as imgur code, as North and NL628 have done. This leads to the next clue:
>
>  [image: clue 2]

The next clue ...

> ... starts with "eye dot stack", which hints at another imgur reference. The code is **JABF5**. The **JAB** is taken verbatim from the picture and **F5** key means "reload" in many browsers; the associated icon is usually one or two circular arrows. The next clue is:
>  
>  [image: clue 3]

The last clue ...

> ... shows **Terra** crisps, the number **one** and an iPhone **X**. From [previous lives](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52685/an-unfortunate-conundrum-involving-extremes), I know that "terra" and "one" can bet rot13'd to give other valid words. "Terra onex" transformed with rot13 is **green bark**.
>
>  Now [green bark](https://www.arboretum.harvard.edu/green-bark/) can be found in a forest, but it doesn't stand out t me as something that's worth hiding in a puzzle. Also, if the answer is correct, the rot13 is not really indicated. Perhaps it's something puzzlers do out of habit without thinking too much about it.

Comment: When someone asks you "What color is bark?" what's the first color that comes to your mind?

Comment: but isn't that stuff moss?

Comment: I would think bark is brown

Comment: ... the answer... I could've just guessed randomly

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer:

Following what North did and

> Typing the following 34fap into imgur gives you the picture:
>  
>  [image]

Then we see that this is a rebus whose first couple things get

> Eye, Dot, Stack

Which seems a lot like

> I.stack, which is probably another imgur.

(Help from nathoenk ) We write it as

> JbYEK because KEY backwards is YEK and we get
>  
>  [image]

Comment: Jab, and flip key?

Comment: The clue is 34faP, figured that was a i.stack.imgur.com thing. I put in i.stack.imgur.com/34faP

Comment: jablock? lol it sounds like an adblock

Comment: Stuck again WELZ

Comment: I think you got lucky with that imgur, has nothing to do with the puzzle.

Comment: I think the next image is [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JABF5.png). For the code: It's JAB + the reload "key" on many browsers. (And I have an inkling that the answer will have to be rot13'd somehow.)

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer:

> Typing the following 34fap into imgur gives you this following picture:
>  
>  [image]

Idk what to do next.

Comment: Ugh how do you hide the images

Comment: I know that the blue blocks are from the game "Stack". Also, the JAB, is from https://www.dcgroup.com.au/testimonials/ this.

Comment: the first two suggest "i.stack" to me, part of a url to another image?
I don't get the latter two though...

Comment: just maybe, you could take the 51 from the image, and JAB to create anotehr shortened url of the same sort as for that one? I'm not sure where the previous one was input though

Comment: any ideas? I tried literally all combos of *jab* upper case lower case permutations, etc. not going anywhere...i hav a feeling the key is useful

Comment: @WELZ ofc ofc ofc and also this thing is driving me crazy. im using ur past puzzles to try and fig it out smh

Comment: @NL628 try JbYEK, since there are symbol before b, and key reverse to yek